# Images are not showing when deploying to device in jquery mobile app

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile and Jquery Mobile Flat UI theme to develop an app using Intel XDK IDE.
 Every thing is working fine as soon as I convert it into apk and test it into my device the images of some part is not showing me in the device but it is working fine on browser.

I have checked the URL is fine.

```
 <div style="width:30%; display:table-cell;">
  <a onclick="changepage('#pickup');" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <div style="background-color:#ff0080;padding:10px;color:white;border-radius:3px;margin:10px;width:auto; height:auto;">
  <img src="loaded.png" width="100%" height="100%">                        
<!--This Image is not showing to me when deployed-->
    </div>
      <p style="margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:0px;font-size:12px;" >Pick Up</p>
       </a>
   </div>
```

What should I do I am going wrong some where please help. I am new to JQM.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute path to the image must be in the src

Comment: It is the absolute path, all other images which are placed here are working

Comment: [Solved] I had just edit height with auto from 100%.